# Intellij Idea not showing source code files

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea

I have a problem with intellij idea. Previously I used Visual Studio and now I decided to try to write code with Intellij. But it seems to me incomprehensible. I created new project (Android gradle application) and I cannot find where the source code is:

[image]

There a a bit of some files and no source code files. And when i opened folder containing my project i found source code subdirectory.

[image]

All source code files are in "Third" folder. But this folder is not shown in "project" panel. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried clicking on "drop arrow" next to the text "Project"? It is on the third row from the top.

It gives you the options of selecting between "project", "Android", and "Package".

Please select "Android" and see it you can find the files.

p.s. just noticed this even though it was posted a while back. Pls kindly tick correct answer if it works out for you. Thx.